# regex - what is the pattern for floating point digit next to unit

Tags: php, regex

basically I want to match a simple thing in a str but only want to return the first part of this match.  This is what I want to look in.

Jo 4.5 Oz cold and flu stuff to drink.

and what I want to do is return the 4.5 but only when the match is followed with a variation of the once unit.

Here is my guess

```
/([0-9]*\.?[0-9])(?:[\s+][o(?<=\.)z(?<=\.)|ounce]?=\s)/i
```

on matching:

```
4.5oz
4.5 oz
4.5 o.z.
4.5 oz.
4.5         oz.
4.5ounce
4.5Ounce
4.5 Oz.
```

but I get when I run it as of yet.

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/([0-9]*\.?[0-9])(?:[\s+][o(?<=\.)z(?<=\.)|ounce]?=\s)/i', 'Jo 4.5 Oz cold and flu stuff to drink.', $matches);
```

Any help would be great.  Thank you 
Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need a less complex pattern like:

```
preg_match('/
      (\d+(\.\d+)?)              # float
      \s*                        # optional space
      ( ounce | o\.? z\.? )      # "ounce" or "o.z." or "oz"
   /ix',                         # make it case insensitive
   $string, $matches);
```

Then either look at result `$matches[1]` or make the remainder an assertion with by enclosing it in `(?=...)` or so.

Comment: yeps that is about where I got.. /([\d]+.{1}[\d]+)(?:\s*o\.?z\.?|ounce)/i .. but I think yours is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably a little more simple than what you're trying there. Give this expression a try:

```
\s[\d]+.{1}[\d]+\s*(oz|ounce|o.z.|oz.)
```

Or with full php:

```
$test_string = 'Jo 4.5 Oz cold and flu stuff to drink.';
$returnValue = preg_match('/\s[\d]+.{1}[\d]+\s*(oz|ounce|o.z.|oz.)/i', $test_string, $matches);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check if they use a . or a , you could use:

```
\d+(.|,){1}\d+\s*(ounce|o\.?z\.?)
```

or

```
 $returnValue = preg_match('/\d+(.|,){1}\d+\s*(ounce|o\.?z\.?)/ix', $test_string, $matches);
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want named patterns try this:

```
$returnValue = preg_match('/(?P<amount>\d+(.|,){1}\d+)\s*(?P<unit>(ounce|o\.?z\.?))/ix', $test_string, $matches);


print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4.5 Oz
    [amount] => 4.5
    [1] => 4.5
    [2] => .
    [unit] => Oz
    [3] => Oz
    [4] => Oz
)
```

Comment: no that didn't but /([\d]+.{1}[\d]+)(?:\s*oz|ounce|o.z.|oz.)/i did on the $match[1] .. but is there a better way to do the point .. in case of typo's .. hmmmm

Comment: yeah sorry, i forgot to remove the \s (checking for whitespace). Not sure what you mean by "a better way to do the point.. in case of typos" -- did you mean if they used a comma instead? you could use: \d+(.|,){1}\d+\s*(ounce|o\.?z\.?) and then be sure to use ix for ignore case and extended...